# Drawing a canvas on another canvas is blurry. How can I fix it?

Tags: html, animation, canvas, sprite

I've been working with some HTML5 canvas experimentation and has a series of tech experiments *edit* https://github.com/AlexChesser/jsSprite (WSAD,Q,E,X keys on the Minotaur key demos, add C and B on the Zombie Demo)

If you look at demo number 1:  `01-draw_minotaur.php` you'll see an image drawn directly on the canvas, and it looks nice and sharp.

However, if you compare to the demo where I put the Minotaur on a canvas then draw that canvas on the parent, the result is blurry: `03-drawn_minotaur_on_canvas.php`

How can I make sure the canvas on canvas drawing isn't blurry?

**EDIT** full code is up on GIT: https://github.com/AlexChesser/jsSprite

**edit2:** note that google has flagged my domain as malware (which to be fair, since hosting provider was hacked there was a brief moment that there was some sort of malware in there) rather than leave the vulnerable link up, I've updated to point exclusively to the source in github.

Comment: First link is now flagged as malware by google. :(

Comment: thanks. I've updated the link. It was flagged as Malware and I have removed it, but there's no guarantee my webhost won't get hacked again.

Comment: time for a new webhost, methinks. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a tricky one!

For canvas, you don't actually use Style to determine its width and height.

So by you setting the style of the canvas you are actually distorting the canvas.

So writing `<canvas id="game" width=512 height=512> </canvas>` in your main page will fix your problem.

I tested it to confirm that was indeed the problem, so if there's still something wrong, let me know and I'll send you my code.

Also shouldn't it just be `MainContext.drawImage(m.canvas, 0, 0);` ? Otherwise you're squishing the Minotaur?

Comment: I'll check right now! Thanks again Simon.  ... (edit) 100% right on both counts.  Previously the Mino wasn't coming out squished, but it was something odd with style.  Now got it rolling.  I *think* i can finally get to basic game logic now!  Thanks again!

Comment: please don't feed the Minotaur, just smile politely, and move to the next animal.